# Sort Repeater fields alphabetically

Tags: craft3, plugin-supertable, sort

I have a supertable with over 79 repeater fields.

Is there a way I can sort these fields in the frontend alphabetically?
For example I have:
Romania
Germany
Austria
...
On the frontend I would like the list to be as
Austria
Germany
Romania
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [orderBy](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/super-table/docs/getting-elements/super-table-block-queries#orderBy) parameter to get super table blocks in the specified order. For example, if your super table field is called `countries` and the title field (that you store the country's name in) is called `country_title`, the code would look like this:

```
{% set alphabeticalCountries = entry.countries.orderBy('country_title').all() %}
```